# IBM MobileFirst not returning an access token from server with time out

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM MobileFirst. I just installed the node JS, npm, IBM MobileFirstframework from pod. 
The pod file, code, and mfpclient.plist files structure are given below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MobileFirstPOC' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MobileFirstPOC
pod 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation'
  target 'MobileFirstPOCTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MobileFirstPOCUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var connectionStatusLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var testServerButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func getAccessToken(_ sender: Any) {
        let serverURL = WLClient.sharedInstance().serverUrl()

        self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Connecting to server...\n\(String(describing: serverURL))"
        print("Testing Server Connection")
        WLAuthorizationManager.sharedInstance().obtainAccessToken(forScope: nil) { (token, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                self.title = "Bummer..."
                self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server\n\(String(describing: serverURL))"
                print("Did not recieve an access token from server: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                self.title = "Yay!"
                self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Connected to MobileFirst Server\n\(String(describing: serverURL))"
                print("Recieved the following access token value: \(String(describing: token?.value))")
            }

            //self.testServerButton.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I am getting the below response :

```
("The request timed out.") Optional(Error Domain=WL_AUTH Code=0 "The request timed out." UserInfo={networkMetadata={
    "$bytesSent" = 648;
    "$category" = network;
    "$outboundTimestamp" = 1504007274489;
    "$path" = "http://219.65.97.101:9080/mfp/api/registration/v1/self";
    "$requestMethod" = POST;
    "$trackingid" = "CA6D20C4-C8C5-41F4-AF70-82E54AAFDF7B";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}) Mirror for Optional<Error>
```

Here is the mfpclient.plist structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">; <plist version="1.0"> <dict> <key>protocol</key> <string>http</string> <key>host</key> <string>219.65.97.101</string> <key>port</key> <string>9080</string> <key>wlServerContext</key> <string>/mfp/</string> <key>languagePreferences</key> <string>en</string> </dict> </plist>
```

Comment: Hii, i am facing the same issue on some devices. did u solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Mobilefirst Server is not accessible from your iOS Device. Due to this it's ending up with the timeout error for the request made to MFP Server.

Make sure MFP Server is reachable before making request. This you can verify by doing simple test as mentioned below.

Try to access Mobilefirst Operations Console in phone browser of iOS device. if it opens, your server is reachable else it's not.